# RxJava combine with boolean operators

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android, greendao

I have two `Observables`. `observableDisconnectContact` is responsible to call API request for remove contact and it works properly. Second one `observableDeleteContact` emits true or false if contact was removed from database. I use `greeDao`.

```
Observable<Boolean> observableDisconnectContact = apiClient.observableDisconnectContact(contactModel.getId()) 

Observable<Boolean> observableDeleteContact = contactModelRxDao.deleteByKey(contactModel.getDbId())
```

I want combine both but second observable should start when first is done and return true. I think about use `concat()` and `first()`. But I have to know that both of stream emits result is true. So I use `combineLatest()` or `zip()`. But it is not good idea becuase both streams are running in the same time. I noticed that `first()` operator doesn't work for `zip()` and `combineLatest()`.

How can I combine both `Observables` where second started after first stream is or not if first return false and result of both streams should be as one result.

```
Observable.combineLatest(observableDisconnectContact, observableDeleteContact, new Func2<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(Boolean isDisconnectSuccess, Boolean isRemoveSuccess) {
                return isDisconnectSuccess && isRemoveFromDatabaseSuccess;
            }
        }).subscribe(new Subscriber<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Boolean isDeleted) {
                if (isDeleted) {
                    //TODO
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
observableDisconnectContact
        .flatMap(isDisconnectSuccessful -> {
            if(isDisconnectSuccessful) return observableDeleteContact;
            else return Observable.just(false);
         })
         .subscribe(isBothActionsSuccessful -> {
             if(isBothActionsSuccessful) {
                 //success!
             } else {
                 //something goes wrong
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
observableDisconnectContact
    .filter(new Func1<Boolean, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(Boolean aBoolean) {
            return aBoolean;
        }
    })
    .flatMap(new Func1<Object, Observable<Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Boolean> call(Object o) {
            return observableDeleteContact;
        }
    });
```

Resulted Observable will emit `observableDeleteContact`'s result if `observableDisconnectContact` emitted `true` and filter (not emitting anything) if it was `false`

Comment: It is almost well. If `observableDisconnectContact` emits false it is called just `onComplited()`. Is it possible to emits false?

Comment: @Michael it is possible, please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using proper semantics of success and failure would make more readable code. By that I mean using `Completable` that either completes on success or emits error on failure.

For example:

```
Completable observableDisconnectContact = ...;
Completable observableDeleteContact = ...;

observableDisconnectContact
    .andThen(observableDeleteContact)
    .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
            }
        });
```

Note: code might not compile as I didn't test it anywhere. Please edit if find any errors